# libGDX How to embed libGDX into JavaFX in 2018

Tags: javafx, libgdx, editor

I want to build an editor for my game using JavaFX for the GUI and libGDX for the graphics (Game is also libGDX)

When I looked up how to add a libGDX canvas to AWT, I only found threads from 2014, that use classes, that are no longer in libGDX in 2018 (At least I can't find them)

Can someone help?

Comment: What's about Scene2d of libgdx? It's for creating GUIs like JavaFX. I think it's not recommended to use JavaFX with libgdx.

Comment: I don't like scene2d. It is very limited and hard to design. Also I like the fxml files and css styling

Answer (score 0):

Inside LibGDX create Pixmap (size = render size).
Import BufferedImage
Do something like:

```
//img ... the image you would render normally with LibGDX
private BufferedImage pixmapToBufferedImage(Pixmap img) {
        int w = img.getWidth(),
            h = img();

        int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
        img.getPixels().asIntBuffer().get(pixels);

        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        out.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        return out;
 }
```

BufferedImage is supported in Java 1.8 I think it should work with JavaFX too.